# Fullpage.js how to change the arrows (CSS)

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I'm going crazy here, have tried almost everything (including the things mentioned in the two other older threads about this topic). I simply want to add images instead of the arrows.

Here is my code:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
height: 200px; 
z-index: 4;
top: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
left: 15px;
background: url(../images/left.png) no-repeat;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
right: 15px;
border-width: 38.5px 0 38.5px 34px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
```

Anybody who have got this to work? This should be easy but it isn't...

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction? Are you sure you are overwriting the fullPage.js css file and no the other way around?

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem by simply creating my own arrows. I think the problem was that I Used an old version of your plugin and therefore the instructions I found here on the site didn't. The problem was with other words on my end ;) Your plugin is awesome by the way :)